# Spring Boot Hibernate auto configuration vs manual annotated config

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot Web app that tries to access my database using Hibernate.
I also have a different, none spring boot application that tries to access the same database.

I am trying to configure the spring boot application using the auto configuration approach, defining my DB properties in the application.properties file.

I am configuring the none spring boot app using an annotated class.

For some reason, the Spring Boots auto configuration is acting differently to the annotated class configuration.

If I connect to the database for the first time and create the schema using hibernate ddl, and then I reconnect using the other way of configuration, I get ddl errors, and for example enumerated columns stop working.

Can someone explain why I get different behaviour using the two ways of configuring spring and hibernate and how do I get them to act in the same way? Could this have something to do with the ejb naming strategy property?

Here are the two ways I'm configuring the JPA:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:databaseFiles/hibData/;hsqldb.write_delay_millis=0
spring.datasource.root=sa
spring.datasource.password=1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```

Config class:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseHibConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
            BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:file:databaseFiles/hibData/;hsqldb.write_delay_millis=0");
            ds.setUsername("sa");
            ds.setPassword("1");
            return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, DataSource dataSource){
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("mediabeast.data.hibernate.model");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding the following properties to both configs seemed to fix the errors that stopped the code from working.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
```

however I am still getting the "object already exists" ddl errors on startup when switching configs.